# How to change the colour of specific output lines in python without any external libraries

Tags: python, colors, console, output

Is there a way, without installing external libraries like Colorama, to change some output text in the command console?
[Screenshot of an attempt at using termcolor and failing and also color formatting codes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h95vE.png)

Comment: Please show your code in the question and not in a linked image. It's much easier to read

Comment: It will depend on OS and terminal program how easy/hard it is and which/how many codes you can use, but you can directly pass ANSI escape codes yourself.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/287871/how-to-print-colored-text-to-the-terminal) probable duplicate help?

Answer (score 0):

The most basic appraoch without literally anything else would be to specify the color specifically in each of your `print` strings.

```
print('\033[92m This line will print in green color. \033[0m')
```

For more colors, take a look [here](https://ozzmaker.com/add-colour-to-text-in-python/)

Comment: I tried this and the output is this:

[92m This line will print in green color. [0m